# Vscode error squiggles not working as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My VScode is not detecting even the simplest c++ syntax error for me:
[image]

Apparently IntelliSense is working fine, since it detected the error in the `test` function, whereas the error in the function below goes ignored. Also, if I get rid of one of the variables in the second function (which makes it inconsistent with the declaration in the header file), IntelliSense will be able to catch this error as well, but any error appearing in the body of the second function is ignored.

The complete code can be found in this repo:

https://github.com/cmu-db/bustub

Comment: I've added the C++ tag, because it might be specific to it. I think the macros are confusing IntelliSense, causing it to skip that part. Can you show how they are defined? Besides, I realize that you want to show the red squiggles and that this requires a picture, but it would be better if you also added the code as text. Thank you!

Comment: it's also very important to know context. `init` is a legal ISO identifier (`std::ios::init` and several more) as well there is something else that might be act as legal typename (I recall there is Init, not sure about `init`)

Comment: That was just an error I created randomly with no meaning at all. I just want to demonstrate the fact that only error outside the class function can be detected.

Comment: what if you remove `INDEX_TEMPLATE_ARGUMNTS`

Comment: it's not clear the hell those macroses are and that content might be 100% of reason why it happening. E.g. `INDEX_TEMPLATE_ARGUMNTS` is actually  `template` clause and class is template class then any code in that function _can_ be legal in time of instancing, only compiler can decide that. Does class have base class or not, is that base template or not also matters. IS analyzer is just a lexxer with some additional hacks, it doesn't repeat compiler's procedure

Answer (score 1):

Pure speculation that your `Init` function is a template function. On my end, IntelliSense do not show errors in template functions.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. The C/C++ extension's IntelliSense doesn't seem to work with template functions. I've raised an issue on the extension's GitHub repo.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7978